# LogCat Missing from Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio, logcat, missing-features

I recently installed Android Studio 3.1.3 on my laptop in order to start learning android/mobile development (I am still new to all of this). The LogCat option seems to be missing though (refer to images below)

[image: image showing the missing alt-6 from Tool Windows]

---

[image: image showing the missing LogCat tab]

What I tried to do in order to fix the problem:

-uninstalling and reinstalling android studio (along with updating it...)

-researching the problem (no useful results as all the solutions were to press alt-6 or go to View->Tool Windows)

It would be a huge help/relief if someone knows how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using canary version?

Comment: If you just need any logcat output you can either use the classic android-sdk-windows\tools\monitor.bat or call "adb logcat" in commandline

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know it is an old question, but I encountered this problem at least twice so it might help someone.

The problem seems to be the path of the project you're looking at.
It should be pointing to the folder containing the 'app' and 'gradle' folders inside your project.

1. Go to File > Open
2. Select the folder with the 'app' folder inside your project
3. Press 'Open'

If you see something like this you can now probably open the Logcat window with alt-6 or View->Tool Windows.

[image: Logcat UNLOCKED]

Note that for some reason, it didn't work for me at first until I opened the app folder, run a build and then opened the folder containing the app folder.

Comment: goddammit, been looking for this for the past few months

Comment: what about for iOs?

Comment: For iOS please use CMD+6 @JoãoAbrantes

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 8):

You need to sync your project and then Logcat will show up

Comment: Funny, but true!

Comment: This worked for me.
It was not visible anywhere int he IDE, but magically appeared when I synced.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this as I did: If you are developing a `react-native` app, be sure that you import only the `android` folder of the project.
If you import the whole project, then among other things, logcat is nowhere to be found!

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Mac.

Comment: this option is missing, please check the images

Comment: Just Try pressing Keyboard Shortcut

Comment: if not then goto sdk->platform->platform-tools-> and run adb logcat

Comment: I pressed the shortcut but nothing happened

Comment: where is the sdk of your 2nd comment located in?

Comment: i dont know where you install adroid sdk but if you are using windows i know the default location of android sdk is C:\user\Username\Appdata\Local\Android\sdk\platform\platform-tools\

Comment: or try window+ R and type 'Appdata' then navigate Local\Android\sdk

Comment: This is not an answer and suggestion of run adb from the command line is lame.

Answer (score 0):

I closed "Logcat" by accident via right click -> "Remove From Sidebar".
I was able to restore it with these steps:

```
Launch your current App on an emulator.

This should create a "Run" Tab on the Sidebar. 

Click on the "Run" Tab and find the "Modify Run Configuration..."
(Wrench) icon and launch it.

Change the tab to "Miscellaneous".

Check the box next to "Show logcat automatically"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution if Logcat doesn't even show up in View->Tool Windows!

But if it does: click it and it may show up at a different location than it used to be. Without recognizing I had shoved it to the top left  where the project tab is shown. You can now click on the gear wheel on the tab and select move to bottom left (that is the default location).

This was the solution for my "logcat not showing".

Answer (score -5):

Press **Alt+6** inside Android Studio to open Logcat monitor.

Then, Do the following steps:-

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Open Android Monitor Window(at the bottom of android studio).
3. Here you will see the drop down in right corner.
4. Select **Show only selected Application**.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I don't understand how it received negative results.